# spring oauth2: resource server without authorization server

Tags: oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I need some lights about convenience of using an autheorizarion server in my project scope.

We're realising and deploying our services into customer environment.

1. Customer infrastructure already provides an authentication mechanism in order to authenticate users.
2. This mechanism intercepts all comunications and redirects user to a "login" form.
3. After that, user is redirected to our service and we've to handle and digest it and respond with an JWT token.

Here is where I'm feeling lost:

I'm thinking about:

1. using spring-oauth2 in order to request a JWT token to an authorization server, or
2. using spring-oauth2 in order to auto-generate an JWT token and validate it. I don't know if it's possible.

My question is, since user is already authenticated, have it sense to use an oauth2 authorization server, **using client-credentials** in order to authentication client against our resource services?

Short question would be, could I use spring-oauth2 librearies in order to generate a JWT without an authorization server?

Answer (score 0):

You technically can do it, but I would discourage you from doing that. Access tokens in a system should be issued centrally, by a dedicated service. Otherwise, it will be hard to maintain the infrastructure. If your services will start to issue JWTs, then they will also have to provide the public keys for others to validate these JWTs. Keys management, access token contents management, and any rules of mapping user information into claims - will now become part of your service and it will unnecessarily complicate its implementation.

If the customer's authentication mechanism issues a JWT, why not use that one for request authorization? If that one is insufficient, I would recommend having an Authorization Server (or a dedicated service), that can perform [Token Exchange](https://curity.io/resources/learn/token-sharing/#exchanging-a-token) and exchange the original JWT for a new one.

Comment: The problem is that customer IPD doesn't provide JWT, I need to generate them. Is it possible to configure spring-oauth2 library in order to only check JWT signature and if it's out of range?

Comment: If what you mean is that you want a spring application that only verifies JWTs, then it is possible. What you need is the OAuth2 Resource Server spring library. You can see an example of that implemented here: https://curity.io/resources/learn/spring-boot-api/

Comment: I took a look at above link. I don't quite figure out example service only verifies jwts without an authorization server, since it's configured to point to an authorization server. What I meant is: is it possible an service could check only signature and validation without an authorization server?

Comment: The validation is done without an authorization server. What you need (normally from an authorization server) is the public key required to verify the JWTs signature. Pointing the configuration to the server's OIDC metadata endpoint is a shorthand method. You can configure the resource server manually - provide the necessary keys and tell the resource server which claims it should validate and what values they should have. Another solution would be to use e.g. [jose4j](https://bitbucket.org/b_c/jose4j/wiki/Home) instead of Spring and validate JWTs manually.